# Oracle 10G regexp for Name

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I am trying to write a regexp_replace to create a "Friendly" name for some employees.  They are currently stored as `FIRST <POSSIBLE MIDDLE INITIAL> LAST <POSSIBLE SUFFIX> <MULTIPLE WHITESPACE> SITE_ID`

For example,

```
JOHN SMITH          ABC
JOHN Q SMITH        ABC
JOHN Q SMITH III    ABC
```

I am trying to write a regex so that I will end up with:

```
Smith, John
Smith, John Q
Smith III, John Q
```

The ABC "Site ID" doesn't need to be included in my output.

This is what I tried with little success:

```
regexp_replace(
    employee_name, 
    '^(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)',
             '\3, \1 \2'
)
```

Also, I am using Oracle 10G.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Would `JOHN Q III` have the middle name Q and the last name III (`III, John Q`), or the last name Q and the suffix III (`Q III, John`)? This sort of name-mangling is always risky, because people's names don't always accord with our preconceptions; for example, what if the last name contains a space, like that of Gabriel García Márquez?

Comment: Yes.  John Q III would have the middle name Q and the last name III.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your names don't show the problems ruakh points out, i.e., there aren't single-letter names or surnames, and no Hispanic names, you can try this regexp:

```
^(\S+)\s(\S\s)?(\S+)(\s\S+)?\s\s+\S+$
```

The replacement should be:

```
\3\4, \1\2
```